# Searching Between dates where STOP date is null

Tags: mysql, jsp, date

I need your help.
The following is my database table.
http://i42.tinypic.com/10xh4j7.png
A small request to please have a look at the image.

My problem is, when I want to retrieve the rate from date_from and date_to.
For Eg: Lets say retrieving_date = 2013-11-14.
rs = stat.executeQuery("select rate from rate_chart where '"+retrieving_date+"' BETWEEN date_from AND date_to");

This query gives me my required result, for the 11th month.
I get 10.40 as my required rate with the above query.

Lets say, rate has never been changed since 2013-11-26, and now my retrieving_date is 2013-12-20. And now, when I try to execute the above query, it doesn't work. No errors but doesn't give me the last rate. In my case, is 10.80 as mentioned in the above image.

I actually want to search between dates even if the stop date or (date_to) is null.

No, idea how to go forth with this. Stuck for a while now.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please edit your question to include your screenshot here.  Should that link ever break in the future, this question will lose its context.  Plus, many people don't like going to external sites to get additional information - you'll have a greater likely hood of someone responding if you include the picture here.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome Derek. I get your point. Would be careful in future mate !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the stop date (or date_to) is null, set it to the current date.

Comment: Dear BWS, now how to determine whether stop_date or (date_to) is null, as the loop would terminate without giving me any result. If it returns as null, then I can add current date. But won't be able to figure out when it would be null.

Comment: something like this:  select rate from rate_chart where '"+retrieving_date+"' BETWEEN date_from AND coalesce(date_to,currdate())" the coalesce function will use currdate if date_to is NULL.

Comment: I am using JSP, and I think currdate() is not supported. Can you please give me a jsp current date function ?

Comment: Thank you BWS, you helped me out and I used now() function. I got what I required. Appreciate it mate.